# unable to get ng-show to work properly

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am trying to show a div only if the results of account creation is successful.

html:

```
<div class="panel-title" data-ng-show="createNewUserSuccess">User Account Successful</div>
```

controller js:

```
$scope.createNewUser = function(isValid) {
        // initialization
        $scope.createNewUserSuccess = false;

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {
            console.log("Creating New User ..");

            UserPost.save( ... , function(data) {
                if(data.status === 'OK'){
                    $scope.createNewUserSuccess = true;

                    console.log('User successfully created.');

                } else if(data.status === 'NOT OK'){
                    ...
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However it is not working as expected, and there are error message i can use for debugging.

Comment: what are error messages in console?

Comment: keep   $scope.createNewUserSuccess = false; out side of function. It will work..

Comment: @pankajparkar There are no error messages, AJAX POST went through, and nothing happened after that.

Comment: @Ved It didn't work. :/

Comment: @OhChinBoon  use `data.statusText` instead of `data.status`, because data.status return code like 404, 200, etc.

Comment: @OhChinBoon you are making mistake. A I told you declare   $scope.createNewUserSuccess = false; outside of function and change it to true after AJAX call inside createNewUser method.

Comment: You should post your complete code here.

Comment: please create a fiddle to replicate your problem. fiddle also gives you options to create mock services.